# What is the most precise delay/sleep function in python

Tags: python, time, delay

I was making an auto-clicker which has a cps of about 1500, to tune the cps to about 100-1200 cps I need a delay of accuracy about 1ms. Through my experimentation with the time library got me an accuracy of about 15ms-20ms which brings the cps up to 63 only.

This is the click function

```
def thread():
    while run:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("c"):
            x, y = pyautogui.position()
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)
        time.sleep(delay)
```

And this is the cps tester function

```
def print_cps():
    state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    while run:
        total = 0
        prev = time.time()

        while (time.time() - prev) < 0.5:
            a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
            if a != state_left:  # Button state changed
                state_left = a
                if a < 0:
                    total += 1
        out = "\rAverage CPS: " + str(total/(time.time()-prev))
        sys.stdout.write(out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

time.perf_counter() has more accuracy than time.time().

It uses internal clock kinds, 100ns accuracy(windows)
In my experiance, I got ~0.0000002 =200ns accuracy.

more detail:
https://peps.python.org/pep-0564/#annex-clocks-resolution-in-python

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use time.sleep() function for this. Then you won't need to use any loops.

Refer to this:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the question itself, the time.sleep function can only precisely sleep for about 10-50ms but I needed a delay precise to 1 ms